# Numerical comparison of two integrals and a function :

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions, number-theory, prime-numbers

Consider the following integral:

$$S(q)=\int_{x=2}^q\sin^2\left(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x}\right)dx$$

And consider the functions :

$$R(q)=\frac{q}{\log(q)}$$

$$T(q)=\int_2^q\frac{1}{\log(x)}dx$$

I want to compare them with each other ( at least numerically for large interval of value  )

If graph for very large intervals (upto atleast $10^4$) possible please add (please add three graphs in one axis system , so that I can compare)

(Does numerics suggest  $S(q) \sim R(q)$ or $T(q)$? )

See ; Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232

Note : Can't calculate the first integral on Mathematica for large values

Comment: Plotting the first integrand shows it's highly oscillatory. Other than throwing (a lot) more precision at it and/or using `LevinRule`, I can't think of a straight-forward way of efficiently computing it. Maybe someone else can think of a way, but I think your best bet might be to figure out analytically how to make the integrand nicer.

Comment: Hopefully you are aware that `LogIntegral[]` is built-in? Additionally: perhaps you could explore using `NDSolve[]` for your $S(q)$; e.g. `sol = NDSolveValue[{s'[q] == Sin[Exp[Log[Pi/2] + LogGamma[q] - Log[q]]]^2, s[2] == 0}, s, {q, 2, 10}]`.

Comment: Running `NIntegrate[Sin[(π Gamma[x])/(2 x)]^2, {x, 2, 10^4}, Method -> "LevinRule", MinRecursion -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 50]` gives out an answer without warnings, but I can't really judge its validity.

Comment: Can I get a graph of them three in one axis system for  q at least 10^4? You can give it as an answer to me . I just need the rough inter- comparison.

Comment: Not unless you can properly compute the function values up to $q=10^4$

Comment: Why is this issue? Due to wild oscillation?

Comment: Because the integrand is extremely bad-behaving. You can’t just get a rough estimate when it oscillates like that, the rough answer is going to be wrong and possibly by a lot. Also, since $\Gamma(x)/x$ grows fast, this oscillation will only get worse as you go to higher values ot $q$.

Comment: What could be the maximum enough value for which accuracy maintains and is withing limits?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107735/discussion-between-imas145-and-bambi).